# Admob not dsiplaying real ads in production

Tags: ionic-framework, admob

I have published an app in the playstore yesterday. The app is created with ionic v1. Even after publishing it, i get to see only test ads instead of real ads. The admob account associated with it is old, created months ago. and in the ionic admob api script, isTesting is set to false. can you please let me know, is there something i was missing? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

just Replace Test Ad unit id with your App ad unit id created on AdMob account.